# PHP strstr() function replacement

Tags: php, function, php-5.2, strstr

Here is an example of how I am using **strstr** on my localhost on PHP 5.3.10

```
<?php
$string  = '25_testing';
$test = strstr($string, '_', true); // As of PHP 5.3.0
echo $test; // prints 25
?>
```

Well, I uploaded my files on my hosting server but they are running off of PHP 5.2 so the function `strstr($string, '_', true)` does not work.  Is there an alternative I can use, to get the same results?

Comment: Odd, that function's been in PHP since v4. There shouldn't be any operational difference. How does it "not work" for you? Get nothing back? Something other than 25?

Comment: I get: PHP Warning: Wrong parameter count for strstr().  So I could take out the true parameter but that would give me a different result, I need that in there to grab the characters before the underscore

Comment: Ah. doh. It's right there in the docs. the 3rd param was added in PHP 5.3. I'll just slink off into a corner and have some coffee and wake up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this...

First you return the string after "_" (including itself) and then replace it with nothing. Not very nice but it works ;)

```
<?php
    $string = "25_testing";
    echo str_replace(stristr($string,"_"),"",$string);
?>
```

or

```
<?php
    $string = "25_testing";
    echo str_replace(strstr($string,"_"),"",$string);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use combination of `strpos` and `substr`:

```
<?php
$string  = '25_testing';
$test = substr($string, 0, strpos('_')); //maybe check if strpos does not return FALSE
echo $test; 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Drop the `true`, and slice the length of the needle off the end of the result.